# Как сделать выборку MySQL чтобы значения в колонке содержали значения из списка

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы, из одной я могу выбрать список нужных мне id:

```
SELECT id FROM `table_with_id` WHERE parent_id = "100500"
```

А в другой есть поле alias, которое содержит эти id из списка вот в таком виде: `category_id=1`

Как мне выбрать из второй таблицы все подходящие мне строки в которых значения поля alias были бы равны `category_id={{любое значение из моей первой выборки}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два основных способа реализации такого запроса: [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) и [in/any](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

Если поле называется `alias`, то запросы могут выглядеть как-то так:

В первом случае вам нужно объединить таблицы по соответствующим полям

```sql
select *
from table2 t2
join table_with_id t on
    t2.alias = concat('category_id=', t.id) and
    t.parent_id = 100500
```

Во втором используем подзапрос:

```sql
select *
from table2 t2
where t2.alias in (
    select concat('category_id=', t.id)
    from table_with_id t
    where t.parent_id = 100500
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для второй таблицы нужно использовать в `WHERE` функцию `IN`, в которой выполняем первый запрос. Приме:

```
SELECT id FROM `table2` WHERE category_id IN (SELECT id FROM `table_with_id` WHERE parent_id = "100500")
```

Comment: Я наверное не совсем правильно описал задачу. Не поле называется category_id, а его значение равно "category_id={{}}"

Comment: немного отредактировал вопрос

Comment: кхм.  `fieldname IN ( select concat('category-', id)) .... )` что ли?